# Running into an issue with Coding to an interface in java (intelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, interface, package

We're recreating the List interface along with the classes ArrayList and LinkedList in my DSA class right now to show the inefficiencies in both regarding add/remove | get/set respectively.

The professor gave us a concept I've never heard of before which is "Coding to an interface." it seemed logical to help remove redundancies, however I ran into an issue and I'm not sure if it's an IDE problem, or if this is expected behavior.

When setting up an ArrayList like this(Using custom Interface and Classes, not from the util package) :

```
public class foobar{
    List<String> arraylist;

    public foobar(){
      arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
      ...
```

The size() method that's within the ArrayList class is not found, but is within the ArrayList class.

however, when the ArrayList is instantiated without coding to an interface, ie.

```
 ...
 ArrayList<String> arraylist;
 public foobar(){
 arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
 ...
```

the size() method is available.

Is this proper behavior? 
Maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept and what I've been reading on coding to an interface,  but it seems like the only methods available are the methods from the interface that are defined in the class.

edit: Thanks for all of the replies! I read up more on polymorphism and everything is making sense now. Sorry for the dumb question I wasn't understanding why it was working that way

Comment: Based on your description, the `size` method seems to be defined in the `ArrayList` (implementation), but not in the `List` `interface` itself.  So when you use `List`, although it's backed by the `ArrayList`, it can only act as a `List`, because that's all it guarantees. This is known as polymorphism

Comment: If you expect ALL implementations of `List` to be able to provide a `size` method, then you need to define that contract in the `List` `interface`

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has bothered to place an answer I encourage you to follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

It appears that to use List and ArrayList as you have above, you would want to use something like this...

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```